# What is the `js` gtags.js command?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, single-page-application, google-tag-manager

The embed code for Google Analytics (well, GA via google tag manager's gtags.js) looks like:

```
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=REDACTED"></script>
<script>
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
    gtag('js', new Date());

    gtag('config', 'REDACTED');
</script>
```

I'm building an SPA app, and I'd like to know what I need to do a virtual pageview - Google's documentation leaves out anything about the `js` command, and I don't want to leave any stones unturned...

1. What is the line `gtag('js', new Date());` doing?
2. If I tell the `config` command in the snippet to not register a pageview, and then call `gtags('config', 'REDACTED', {...})` later (with page info in the `{...}`), do I need to execute `gtag('js', new Date());` before the config call?

Comment: Did you see this? https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/single-page-applications#measure_virtual_pageviews

Comment: (For an SPA, virtual pageviews are what you want.)

Comment: @MattBrowne I've already read that, what I'm asking about is the `js` event. My question is about whether the JS event is involved in a pageview, since the JS event seems to go unmentioned in the documentation.

Comment: Probably only a Google Analytics employee could tell you exactly what it does, but if I were to guess, I would say it looks like one-time initialization code to let GA know when the JS snippet first executed. I'm not an expert, but based on examples I've seen, you only need to call `gtag('js', new Date())` once. See for example https://bcodes.io/blog/post/installing-gtag-js-analytics-for-single-page-applications

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the relevant code from the gtag JavaScript file:

```
js: function(a) {
    if (2 == a.length && a[1].getTime) return {
        event: "gtm.js",
        "gtm.start": a[1].getTime()
    }
}
```

It would seem that this is an init function - it checks that some sort of command array exists and has an expected length (probably to make sure it hasn' been initialized before) and then emits the gtm.js event and the timestamp (`a[1].getTime` checks for the Date object that has been passed in by testing for a getTime method).

So it probably does neither harm nor good to run it multiple times (since it will return a values only once).